# Skipping confirmation popup or overriding for Bluetooth Device pair in windows from UWP app?

Tags: windows, uwp, bluetooth, popup

While connecting to any Bluetooth device, a yes/no popup appears from windows.

From app, is there any way to programmatically skip this yes/no popup?

Checked few documentation.

Comment: Search for Disable Authentication Agent. However, in this case you must handle pairing manualy.

Comment: Can you provide any link to it for this in UWP? Can custom pairing come in any help to this?

Comment: It was published as an answer for the same question on SO few times. Try to find it, I do not have link. Custom pairing allows to initiate pairing from your code but does not handle pairing requests from device. To handle pairing request you have to use classic Bluetooth API (it can be called from UWP but you need to import functions).

Comment: Does the GATT client work for you?

Comment: The device does not support GATT, it relies on RFComm communication. Also, we need audio transmission via BT not BLE audio...

Comment: After talking with some Bluetooth guys, it seems that you need to use [custom pairing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/devices-sensors/pair-devices) in your scenario.

Comment: @MikePetrichenko any chance you have more info on disabling the auth agent?

Comment: Yes, but since SO does not allow to publish code with copyrights I can not provide it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After talking with some Bluetooth guys, it seems that you need to use **[custom pairing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/devices-sensors/pair-devices)** in your scenario. This feature enables creating your own user interface to interact with the user as needed.

The sample code you could refer here:https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/main/Samples/DeviceEnumerationAndPairing/cs/Scenario9_CustomPairDevice.xaml.cs